# Excel data lookup formula consistently returning the cell below the lookup value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using the formula below to find multiple matching records in a spreadsheet based on the data entered into a cell. The original formula worked fine however was based on a data range. As data is been constantly added to the spreadsheet I made the range a dynamic table (Table2). Now the formula is consistently returning the record below the record that actually matches the targets and I cannot figure out why this is?

My formula is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Table2,SMALL(IF(Table2=$B$1,ROW(Table2)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX(Table2,SMALL(IF(Table2=$B$1,ROW(Table2)),ROW(1:1)),2))
```

Please can anyone help with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Over what range does Table2 span?

Comment: I take it from your use of ISERROR, as opposed to the more efficient IFERROR, that you're using Excel 2003 or earlier?